# Find mathematical operators in Java String?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to be able to tell whether a string is a mathematical expression or not.
The true nature of my problem is to find symbols that do not match with any of these: *, /, +, -, (, ), 0-9 in any given string.

```
if (Pattern.compile("[a-z]").matcher(inputExpression).find()) {
        return ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL;
    } else if (!inputExpression.matches("[-+*/()]") || !inputExpression.matches("[0-9]")) {
        return ErrorType.UNKNOWN_SYMBOL;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? The program works if I remove the second if-statement and expect to find alphabetic symbols in my string.

I tried to do the following: Change the matches method to .find() to find if the pattern is there as follows.

```
if (Pattern.compile("[a-z]").matcher(inputEquation).find()) {
        return ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL;
    } else if (!Pattern.compile("[-*+/]").matcher(inputEquation).find() && !Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(inputEquation).find()) {
        return ErrorType.UNKNOWN_SYMBOL;
    }
```

The code is still not working. I'm having logical errors.

Comment: What is the value of `inputExpression`?

Comment: Does it matter? It's read from System.in. It could be anything really. I'll give you an example: inputExpression = "38+2*3/5+3&"

Comment: The `matches` method checks if the whole string matches the pattern. Not if the string contains something that matches the pattern, which is what you seem to expect. You'll need to use other methods, such as `find` which you are already using in the first line, for that.

Comment: I wanted to check what string you thought should be valid, in case it had any "hidden" invalid chars which might account for the false result.

Comment: Try using `else if (!inputExpression.matches(".*[-+*/()0-9].*")` in the `else if`. Or `else if (!Pattern.compile("[-+*/()0-9]").matcher(inputExpression).find()`. Also, replace `"[a-z]"` with `"[a-zA-Z]"` or just `"\\p{L}"` to match any letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `inputExpression.matches`. It does not *search* the string, it checks if the *whole* string matches. What you need is

```java
if (Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]").matcher(inputExpression).find()) {
    return ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL;
} else if (Pattern.compile("[^-+*/()0-9]").matcher(inputExpression).find()) {
    // [^...] negates a character class
    return ErrorType.UNKNOWN_SYMBOL;
}
```

You don't even need regular expressions to be honest. The following loop acheives the same result and is easier to look at.

```java
String accepted = "-+*/()";
for (int i = 0; i < inputExpression.length(); i++) {
    char c = inputExpression.charAt(i);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') continue;
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL;
    if (accepted.indexOf(c) < 0) return ErrorType.UNKNOWN_SYMBOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code (just replace the method output type and return values as you see fit):

```
private static String check(String inputExpression)
{
    if (Pattern.compile("\\p{L}").matcher(inputExpression).find()) {
        return "ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL";
    } else if (!Pattern.compile("[-+*/()0-9]").matcher(inputExpression).find()) {
        return "ErrorType.UNKNOWN_SYMBOL";
    }
    return "Valid";
}
```

See the [Java online demo](http://ideone.com/RG6fhh)

```
System.out.println(check("9+56"));     = > Valid
System.out.println(check("9+56sdwe")); = >  ErrorType.ALPHABETIC_SYMBOL 
System.out.println(check("^^^"));      = > ErrorType.UNKNOWN_SYMBOL
```

**Details**:

- `\\p{L}` matches any letter (to match ASCII only, use `\\p{Alpha}` here)
- `else if (!Pattern.compile("[-+*/()0-9]").matcher(inputExpression).find())` check if the string contains digits or some of the symbols defined in the character class, and once found, it returns false.